# How to Hide Server/Software Version (Werkzeug & Python) from Superset Response Header?

Tags: python, apache-superset, werkzeug, response-headers, penetration-testing

Any ideas/suggestions on how to hide software/server version in Superset? We hired an information security company to perform an external pen-testing in our servers and one of the issues raised was to hide all the software versions being disclosed on application headers/error messages.

So for example if I execute this command from a terminal:

```
curl -I -k https://localhost:8181/
```

It is disclosing the server information by default (line 5 below).

```
HTTP/1.0 302 FOUND
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 241
Location: https://localhost:8089/superset/welcome
Server: Werkzeug/1.0.1 Python/3.6.10
Date: Mon, 20 Jul 2020 12:07:33 GMT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to your Superset directory. In my case, `cd /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/superset/`
2. Modify `config.py`
3. Find and edit this line: `OVERRIDE_HTTP_HEADERS: Dict[str, Any] = {"Server":""}`
4. Restart Superset and you're done